# Recommended nested data-structure for querying using [python-lifter]

Tags: python, nosql

I am scraping a collection of text documents and building a json object to query with python-lifter.  I currently have data like

```
[
    [
        {name:dad},
        {name:son, dob:2/24/2000}
    ],

    [
        {name:forever_alone, cats:12}
    ]

]
```

I would like to do two different queries based on the existence of the `dob` key: 1) to get son and 2) to get the family that contains the son (dad and son).  As I understand it, a list of lists of dictionaries is not well supported in lifter.  Suspending for a moment the issue that lifter does not yet allow queries on fields that are not on every record, what would be a better, what would be a better structure for lifter?

a list of dictionaries of dictionaries?

```
[
    {
        0:{name:dad},
        1:{name:son, dob:2/24/2000}
    },

    {
        0:{name:forever_alone, cats:12}
    }

]
```

or a dictionary of lists of dictionaries?

```
{18283923:
    [
        {name:dad},
        {name:son, dob:2/24/2000}
    ],

 18283927:
    [
        {name:forever_alone, cats:12}
    ]

}
```

And, given an ideal nested data structure, what are the two queries that would return 1) the son and 2) the family containing the son?

Comment: Is there some type of relationship between `dad` and `son` which is why they are grouped in the same array?

Comment: Yes, they are members of the same family.  The data comes from parsing a bunch of text files (actually asana.com tasks) and they are in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: lifter maintainer here]

This kind of requests is not supported by lifter right now, because lifter will try to lookup queried fields on each object and will raise an error if the field does not exist.

Support for [querying against iterable fields](https://github.com/EliotBerriot/lifter/issues/7) is not good at the moment either.

[An issue](https://github.com/EliotBerriot/lifter/issues/26) has been opened regarding the missing fields problem though,
but anyway, your data structure is not really suited for such queries.

A better data structure would be:

```
families = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'members': [
            {'name': 'dad'},
            {'name': 'son', 'dob':'2/24/2000'}
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'members': [
            {'name': 'forever_alone', 'cats': 12}
        ]
    }
]
```

Then, after previous linked issues has been solved, you could query with something like:

```
Family = lifter.models.Model('Family')
manager = Family.load(families)

# get families with son/dob members
son_dob_families = manager.filter(Family.members.name == 'son', Family.members.dob.exists())\
                          .values(Family.id, Family.members)

# keep only son members with dob

Member = lifter.models.Model('Member')
members = [member for family in son_dob_families for member in family['members']]
sons_with_dob = Member.load(members).filter(Member.name == 'son', Member.dob.exists())
```

This is a theorical API though, it's not implemented yet.